# Codeigniter - accessing variables from an array passed into a page

Tags: codeigniter, variables, arrays, view

I have a controller with an index function as follows:

```
function index() 
{ 
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data['product'] = $this->products_model->get(3); // 3 = product id
    $data['product_no'] = 3;
    $data['main_content'] = 'product_view';
    //print_r($data['products']);
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

This is the get function in the products_model file

```
function get($id)
{
    $results = $this->db->get_where('products', array('id' => $id))->result();
    //get the first item
    $result = $results[0];
    return $result; 
}
```

The products table contains fields such as name, price etc. Please can you tell me how to output variables from $data['product'] after it is passed into the view?  I have tried so many things but nothing is working, even though the print_r (commented out) shows the data - it is not being passed into the view.  I thought it may have been because the view calls a template file which references the main_content variable:

Template file contents:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

but i tried creating a flat view file and still couldn't access the variables.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

your $data array is "ripped" into single variables within the view.

```
print $product;
print $product_no;
print $main_content;
```

Comment: Yes but they are also listed into $this->load->_ci_cached_vars for use within child views that have no data array of their own.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have removed that template file - now the view is a flat html file.  I have also changed the controller index function to


    function index() 
{ 
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data['product'] = $this->products_model->get(3); // 3 = product id
    $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
 

however, I cant access the array variables in the view.  What would the correct code be?  I have tried echo $this->$price, echo $data['price']  -  I'm sure this is dead simple, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Handling headers & footers this way sucks and get's unmanageable pretty quickly.

Try using my [Template library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template), your data will be passed through to the product_view no problem.